# Magnetize a thin cobalt steel rod

Tags: coil

I need to magnetize a 1/16" x 4" cobalt steel ( drill) rod to its maximum strength. I plan to heat the rod past its curie temp before magnetizing for maximum effect.

Can I do this with straight DC ( car batteries ) or should I construct a capacitor discharge system?

How would I calculate the coil wire size needed, and number of turns?
How would I confirm success?

Thank You For Reading,
Bill

Comment: Thank for the input.

I only wish to magnetize the cobalt rod to the fullest magnetic condition possible.

I have read that pre-heating the rod will increase the magnets strength.

I was planning to heat the rod to cherry in in a small Mapp gas fired kiln, then immediately drop it into the coil and apply the magnetizing power. 



I'm completely in the dark concerning the size of the wire, and number of turns needed to produce the magnetizing field required. I have a good supply of 14 awg enameled magnet wire...

Cheers!
Bill

Answer (score 0):

The Curie temperatures for iron and cobalt are 1043 and 1400 K, respectively, which suggests that an electrical heating system may not be your best bet. If you do, a capacitive system would seem the worst way to go, since the amount of energy will be pretty high.

> How would I calculate the coil wire size needed, and number of turns?

For what? Are you planning on trying to make an inductive heater? If the coil is to be used for producing the magnetizing field, that depends entirely on what field you want to produce, and you haven't specified that.

> How would I confirm success?

Put your rod near a magnet, and measure the attractive or repulsive force.

Comment: Also, if this is a drill bit, you might turn the metal to cheese-grade in a flash if you aren't careful about cooling it. Quenching will probably enbrittle it too much, but letting it rest might cause issues too. check the phase diagram for your specific steel and see what works best